# Minecraft suddenly extremely slow

Tags: java, games, minecraft

I recently re-installed the Minecraft client on my laptop. Before this, it worked fine without any issues whatsoever.

Now, I can only get about 5 minute of gamer time before it lags so bad that I cannot play, and then it slows my system down  even after I exit the game.

I did a fresh install of my OS afterwards, since I was planning on that anyways. I am now running a fresh install of Mint and am still having the issue.

I have tried using Open JDK 6 and 7, as well as optifine, using various desktop environments, and setting up the run.sh file as well as anything else in other threads here and elsewhere.

The laptop is a Dell Latitude E6400, with 4GB of ram.

At this point I am stumped.

Comment: What run.sh file? Minecraft comes as a .jar.

Comment: Open up system monitor and see if anything is using more ram/cpu than it should be.

Comment: What resource of your computer is causing Minecraft to be slow? Open up System Monitor or your desktop environment's equivalent and tell us, is it your RAM, hard drive, or CPU that is being used to the extent that it's causing the game to slow?

Comment: _"What run.sh file?"_

There is a thread here where they suggest making a run.sh file in the same directory as the Minecraft.jar and putting

**java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -jar Minecraft.jar**

in it.

Comment: I opened up my system monitor while loading and playing.

It uses 33% of my ram, constantly. 

It uses about 20-27% per CPU, I have two. 

After 8 minute, it suddenly uses 100% of both CPUs and the lag starts. the Memory usage stays the same. 

And the high CPU usage remains really high for about 15-20 minutes after I close the game. 

I turn of all processes when i play Minecraft. The only thing running is system and desktop environment files.

Comment: Maybe you should try using Oracle's JRE? Download the bundle from http://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp and modify your run.sh file to use Oracle's JRE after you've extracted it.

Comment: That worked! 

Oracle's JRE worked like a charm, played a whole 45 minutes, no lag and held steady at 40fps.